# Array sorting in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of the following structure --

The structure of the array is following -

```
    [
        {key:12,value:[{e:1,c:2,d:3},{e:34,c:45,d:90},{e:23,c:89,d:34}]},
        {key:25,value:‌​[{e:12,c:22,d:32},{e:34,c:45,d:90},{e:23,c:89,d:34}]}
    ]
```

I have to sort the columns. How can I go about it?

ng-repeat for this array looks like the following --

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat = "key in array track by $index">
        <td>key.key</td>
        <td>{{key.value[0].e}}</td>
        <td>{{key.value[1].e}}</td>
        <td>{{key.value[2].e}}</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
```

Comment: maybe you could benefit from lodash: https://lodash.com/

Comment: Why not use the native javascript sort()? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What needs to be sorted?

Comment: There are 3 columns (e,c and d). I have to sort their values.

Comment: how does your ``ng-repeat`` look like?

Comment: please give an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `orderBy` filter component of ng module of AngularJS. For example, if you want to sort your columns according to the `key` parameter of the key variable, you can do following,

```
   <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat = "key in array track by $index | orderBy:'key'">
        <td>key.key</td>
        <td>{{key.value[0].e}}</td>
        <td>{{key.value[1].e}}</td>
        <td>{{key.value[2].e}}</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
```

For more information, you can read the [orderBy documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Comment: Yeah for key it's fine but I can't write orderBy:'key.value[0].e' , to sort the 3 columns.

Comment: You don't have to write this. Just write `orderBy:'value[0].e'`